# Haskell implement a filter list with fold function

Tags: haskell, filter, fold

```
filterList :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)] 

>filterList " foo " [( " foo " , 1) , ( " bar " ,2) , ( " foo " ,3)]
[( " foo " ,1) ,( " foo " ,3)]
```

I have figured out two ways to solve this problem ,

```
`first way with list comprehension :` filterList a ((x,y):xs) =[(b,c)|(b,c)<-((x,y):xs),a==b]



  second way with recursive function: 
 filterList2 a []=[]
 filterList2 a ((x,y):xs)|a==x = (x,y):filterList2 a xs
                         |otherwise = filterList2 a xs
```

but I want to solve it with the folder function, and I am stuck.

```
filterList a ((x,y):xs) = foldr filter1 a ((x,y):xs)
                          
filter1 b ((x,y):xs)|b==x = (x,y)
                    |otherwise = filter1 b xs
```

which is not working.

A little help is really appreciated.

Comment: note that the function you pass to the foldr, so here `filter1` is *not* agiven the full list. It is given an element, and the result of the `foldr` on the remaining list.

Comment: The patten `filterList a ((x, y):xs)` does not make much sense either. Since it should work on any list (including an empty), you implement this as `filterList a ls = foldr (filter1 a) ls`.

Comment: Your `foldr` also should have a "base-case", the one if the list is exhausted" as second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both problems with the `filterList` and `filter1` function. The `filterList` function has as pattern:

```
filterList a ((x, y): xs) = …
```

but that does not make much sense, the type signature, and type inference will guarantee that it is a list of 2-tuples. Your pattern here will not work for an empty list, but filtering an empty list is likely still necessary. You thus should simplify it to:

```
filterList a ls = …
```

the [**`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) function is given three parameters:

- the fold function
- the "base-case", which is used when folding an empty list; and
- a list of elements.

But you can not use `a` as base case, since that base case also determines the type of the result. The base case is here the empty list. We also need to pass `a` to the `filter1` function, so we can implement this as:

```
filterList :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
filterList a ls = foldr (filter1 a) [] ls
```

Your `filter1` function works on a list, but that is not how a `foldr` function works. The function you pass to `foldr` will be given an element, and the *result* of folding the rest of the list. Your function thus looks like:

```
filter1 :: Eq a => a -> (a, b) -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
filter1 a (x, y) rs = …
```

Here `a` is the element we have passed we have to look for, `(x, y)` is the 2-tuple we are "folding in", and `rs` is the result of folding the rest of the list. So this is a list that is already filtered.

I leave implementing `filter1` as an exercise.